# run php script every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use setInterval to execute the php script update.php every 10 seconds and refresh div id = verification. For some reason setInterval is preventing the script from functioning. Any suggestions on where to place\change setInterval would be appreciate as I'm stumped (sorry entry level javascript user here). For clarity I omitted all the non-relevant details, such as vars.

```
<div id="verification"></div>

<script id="verification" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'update.php', //php          
        data: "", //the data "caller=name1&&callee=name2"
        dataType: 'json', //data format   
        success: function(data) //on receive of reply
            {
                var foobar = data[2]; //foobar
                $('#verification').html("(<b>" + foobar + "</b>)"); //output to html

            }
    });
});

setInterval(10000); //every 5 secs
</script>
```

Comment: You're missing the function argument to `setInterval`.

Comment: This should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: Didn't you post a very similar question a few hours ago? The difference there was that it used `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

Comment: I tried renaming function () to function verify() and setInterval(verify, 10000); but that failed to work.

Comment: It was flagged as a duplicate question, which is incorrect. I need help with basic syntax not just setInterval.

Comment: You have two `id="verification"`. IDs should be unique.

Comment: Why do you need an `id` on the `<script>`, anyway?

Comment: `10000` is 10 seconds. 5 seconds is `5000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions/Steps/Bugs:

1. Create a separate function to perform `ajax` request
2. Call this function on page load to run it when page is loaded
3. Use `setInterval()` to call the function every `n` seconds
4. `id` should always be unique. You're now using `verification` as if for `<div>` and `<script>`
5. You can remove `id` and `language` attributes of `<script>`. Those are not required.

Code:

```
function update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'update.php', //php          
        data: "", //the data "caller=name1&&callee=name2"
        dataType: 'json', //data format   
        success: function (data) {
            //on receive of reply
            var foobar = data[2]; //foobar
            $('#verification').html("(<b>" + foobar + "</b>)"); //output to html
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(update); // Call on page load
//                ^^^^^^


setInterval(update, 10000); //every 10 secs
//          ^^^^^^
```

Comment: How did 10 seconds become 5 seconds?

Comment: @Barmar I saw comment saying `5 seconds` so. I've updated to use 10 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the function block:

```
setInterval(function() {
  // to do
}, 5000);
```

My suggestion is to go for `setTimeout` as you are running ajax it is not certain that it would complete within 5 seconds. In case if you wana go for it:

```js
var dispatchUpdates = function() {
  setTimeout(pullUpdates, 5000);
};

var pullUpdates = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'update.php',
    data: "",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      var foobar = data[2];
      $('#verification').html("(<b>" + foobar + "</b>)");
      dispatchUpdates(); // next updates
    },
    error: function() {
      dispatchUpdates(); // retry
    }
  });
};

$(dispatchUpdates); //page load
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval()` takes a function (that it should execute) as it's first argument.

Try this:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'update.php', //php          
      data: "",                        //the data "caller=name1&&callee=name2"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format   
      success: function(data)          //on receive of reply
      {
          var foobar = data[2];           //foobar
          $('#verification').html("(<b>"+foobar+"</b>)");     //output to html
      } 
  });
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using setInterval in a wrong way - you can read about it here:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Also please notice that AJAX calls are asynchronous - when program is going forward it doesn't mean that previous AJAX call has ended. You can "wait" for AJAX completition using some jQuery mechanisms like binding [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/) or using [when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Comment: You could also schedule the next call in the callback function of the previous one, using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.